# What does the exclamation mark mean when approaching a door?

Tags: rage

Most doors I come across in the Rage universe do not cause a hand icon to appear, indicating that they can be opened, nor are they locked with a grindable lock. Most actually display a white warning sign as seen here:

[image]

And zooming in a bit:

[image]

I have to admit I haven't been keeping track of doors that become open while you play, so I wanted to know what it is this icon indicates, exactly.

Does it mean "this door won't open **at the moment**", or perhaps "this is indeed a door, **but it will never open**"? Perhaps it means either one depending on the door?

Comment: Maybe they indicate that some DLC will open them up. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes they become openable doors through the story (e.g. entrance/exit in Dead City), sometimes you get a keycard or key to open them (e.g. Gearhead Vault in Subway), sometimes they can be opened by shooting gas tanks behind them (e.g. Wasted Garage) or similar.

However, mostly they're just part of the wall that looks like a door - there seems to be more 'doors' like that than any other.

Comment: I havve had this happen when trying to enter the Wellmaster door. This is when on a mission and Carlson (who you need to talk to) is inside that door. Also the entrance to the well is inside there. Any ideas how to open it?

Comment: @DonCoyle, I'm not sure, but I don't think I could open that door until the mayor gave me the specific quest to go see the Wellmaster.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the door is not openable at all. A red hand icon would mean that the door is openable via other means (key, switch, explosive). I suspect this was put in so that future DLC may change this, but that is only my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

They place it so that you can see that you are indeed properly positioned at a door and it is indeed a door but that it cannot be opened. It is a different style then games where you see doors and you try to get up against it and open it but it just is part of the environment. It's more of an aesthetic and design decision then anything practical, other than the fact that you know you are located properly in place of a door. Makes you think that there is a room behind it, and more things, gives the place a more fleshed-out feel, in my opinion.

Also like mentioned by others, since it isn't a piece of wall that appears like a door, and is apparently programmed as a door "entity", from a programming standpoint it would make things easier to implement the ability to open any of these at a later date through a DLC or occurrence within the game.